# Keras: Use categorical_crossentropy without one-hot encoded array of targets

Tags: python, keras

I have a Keras model that I'm using for a multi-class classification problem.  I'm doing this:

```
model.compile(
    loss='categorical_crossentropy',
    optimizer='adam',
    metrics=['accuracy'],
)
```

I currently have ~100 features and there are ~2000 possible classes.  One-hot encoding the class is leading to memory issues.

Is it possible to use `categorical_crossentropy` with this Keras model while *not* one-hot encoding the class labels.  E.g. instead of having a target look like:

`[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, ...]`

It would just be:

`3`

I looked at the source for `categorical_crossentropy` in Keras and it assumes two tensors of the same shape.  Is there a way to get around this and use the approach I described?

Thanks!

Comment: If you actually look up the definition of categorical cross entropy and how the formula is actually defined , it will become clear why you can't use that measure with integers and have to use one-hot coded  labels , as for your memory problem , is it coming with using generators ?

Answer (score 14):

If your targets are one-hot encoded, use `categorical_crossentropy`.
Examples of one-hot encodings:

```
[1,0,0]
[0,1,0]
[0,0,1]
```

However, if your targets are integers, use `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`.
Examples of integer encodings:

```
1
2
3
```

Comment: Do you still use Dense(nr_of_classes, activation = 'softmax') as output layer when using sparse_categorical_crossentropy?

Answer (score 1):

Could you post the rest of your code? by my understanding when using categorical crossentropy as loss function, the last layer should use a softmax activation function, yielding for each output neuron the probability of the input corresponding to said neuron's class, and not directly the one-hot vector. Then the categorical crossentropy is calculated as

[image]

where the `p`'s are these probabilities. By just outputting the class you wouldn't have access to these probabilities and thus wouldn't be able to compute the categorical crossentropy.